# How do I leverage @media events in Bootstrap with Knockout JS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am building an SPA using knockout and Sammy for my routing and navigation.  I am trying to stay pretty clear in my usage of the MVVM model in that I want all actions to be bound to in my VM.

I am Trying to figure out how to use the Bootstrap responsive Nav bar within that pattern.  I know how to make the Bootstrap nav work with the toggle button and the navbar-collapse, but I feel like I should be doing that within my VM for the sake of Symmetry.

Only thing is I am not sure how to data-Bind against the media query that bootstrap is using to toggle the Nav Bar toggle button and the collapsing portion of the nav.

Am I being foolish in trying to cross the Knockout/Bootstrap streams? Is there a clean way to hook into the Bootstrap ecosystem with knockout Bindings?

Thanks

Tal

Comment: I've not delved into it too much, but there is a library specifically designed to help bridge the gap: [knockstrap](http://faulknercs.github.io/Knockstrap/)

Answer (score 1):

I feel that this is not really something you should do inside a viewmodel. Bootstrap's navbar changes are CSS-based which is fine, to be honest. However, when you want the behavior of the UI to change in ways that Bootstrap doesn't handle, it might still be useful to bind against the media queries. This is how I do it: (using Modernizr)

```
var mediaQueries = {
        xs: 'only screen and (max-width: 767px)',
        smAndUp: 'only screen and (min-width: 768px)'
        // Match these queries to Bootstrap's
    },
    matchMediaQuery = function (mediaQuery) {
        return window.Modernizr.mq(mediaQuery);
    },
    mediaXs = function () {
        return matchMediaQuery(mediaQueries.xs);
    },
    mediaXsObservable = ko.observable(mediaXs());
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    var xsNow = mediaXs(),
        xsPrevious = mediaXsObservable();
    if (xsNow !== xsPrevious) {
        mediaXsObservable(xsNow); // subscribe to this observable and respond accordingly
    }
});
```

Basically what it does is hook the resize event to update the observable utilizing help-functions that implement Modernizr's mediaquery check.